# How do I create an immutable Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried to write an Array that the script cannot mutate; not by adding or popping elements from or to the Array. I tried to do something like this:

```
const arr = [30, 20, 10]
```

but when I tried to add an element to the Array it works.

Can someone please can show me how to define an array that cannot change

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

However, you should note that entries that are themselves Objects can still be modified, unless they are also frozen

```js
const arr = [30, 20, 10, {name: 'Tom', age: 54}, [0]];
Object.freeze(arr);

// arr.push(10); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 3, object is not extensible
// arr.pop();    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property '2' of [object Array]

arr[0] = 5;

arr[3].name = 'Modified';
arr[4][0] = 'Modified';

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you rather want only the size of the array to be fixed but the element values could change, then [`Object.seal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) will do what you want.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
Object.seal(arr);

arr[0] = 4;
//arr.push(-6);   "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 3, object is not extensible"
console.log(arr)
```